# Highcharts Sankey Colors not working in django

Tags: django, highcharts, sankey-diagram

Does anyone know why the sankey chart responds differently in a django compared to just an HTML file that is not in a server. The chart options and the data provided to them is the same and the chart definition is also the same but the rendering of the charts is different. For example, the colors in the server do not work yet on the static HTML they render perfectly. Kindly assist. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dumi

I tried using `django.shortcuts.render` to replicate this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/marensiusb/d5weL1pu/).
All the colors are correct in my browser, I would need a code sample to see where it is going.